# Pass a variable in field_map() function of TEXT::CSV::Simple

Tags: perl, csv

I am using $parser->field_map(qw/id name town/) function of TEXT::CSV::Simple.

I wish to pass a variable to field map function. So instead of passing

```
qw/id name town/
```

I want to pass $var where

```
$var = qw/id name town/.
```

I tried using

```
$var = '\'id\', \'name\' , \'town\'';
$parser->field_map($var);
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

@var=qw/id name town/; $parser->field_map(@var);